# Problems with header in HTML (doesn't cover all the weight)

Tags: html, css, header

I'm new with HTML and CSS and I'm trying to make a page, but I have a problem with the header since it doesn't span the whole width. [Image of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQVY7.png)

Here's my HTML code:

```
<nav class="links"> 
            <a href="#home"> Home </a>
            <a href="#about"> About </a>
            <a href="#products"> Products </a>
            <a href="#services"> Services </a>
            <a href="#locations"> Locations </a>
            <a href="#contact"> Contact us </a>
        </nav>
    </head>
    <body class="body">
        <header>
            <img class="gato" src="Imagenes/cat.jpg">
            <h1>ArchiteXture</h1>
            <p></p>
            </header>
```

And here's my CSS code:

```
header{
    background-color:#ACBBF0;
    padding:20px;
    width:96%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-color:#5666A0;
}
.body{
    background-color:#CBDFE8;
    width:96%;
    border-right:3px;
    border-bottom:3px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#5666A0;
    margin-left:2%;
}
.links{
  background-color: #ACBBF0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.13) 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.17) 50%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.19) 50%);
  background-size: 13px, 29px, 37px, 53px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:3px;
  border-left:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#5666A0;
}
```

I tried to remove paddings, and margin.
I also tried to use the F12 tool in Chrome to inspectionate the code, but I don't see why I get that space between the header and the body since body is the "father".
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean width instead of weight?

Comment: Which space you are trying to remove. The margin one or the white spaces between them.

Comment: Your `nav` tag should be inside the `header` tag not `head` tag

Comment: Hi, guys, thanks for answering. I already put my nav inside the header. Also, what I mean is that I want that "box" to close, I dont want the blue color of the body to invade my header, as you can see in the picture.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's three main errors:

- The padding and margin should be set to 0. Sol.: Remove all padding
  and margins at once ( with `*{margin:0; padding;0;}`,
- There're some wrong ubicated closing tabs (line 9). Sol.: correct order of opening and closing tabs (1st head, 2nd body),
- and you don't give an addaptative size to the photo. Sol.: give the size in percentage (the width or the height, as you prefer).

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
    background-color:#ACBBF0;
    padding:20px;
    width: inherit;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#5666A0;
}
.body{
    background-color:#CBDFE8;
    width: inherit;
    border-right:3px;
    border-bottom:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#5666A0;
}
.links{
  background-color: #ACBBF0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.13) 50%, transparent 50%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.17) 50%),
  linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.19) 50%);
  background-size: 13px, 29px, 37px, 53px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#5666A0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="links">
    <a href="#home"> Home </a>
    <a href="#about"> About </a>
    <a href="#products"> Products </a>
    <a href="#services"> Services </a>
    <a href="#locations"> Locations </a>
    <a href="#contact"> Contact us </a>
  </nav>
  <header>
    <img class="gato" src="photo.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <h1>ArchiteXture</h1>
    <p></p>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did it but is still the same. I don't know why do I have that space with the color of the body when my header has the same weight.

Comment: Check also the CSS file.

Comment: The code now is right, at the top of the CSS file you must include `*{padding:0;margin:0;}`, as I have written in the answer. You should avoid that type of comments, and try following the guidelines of StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, my apologies. I included that in my code but it still the same with the right side of the website, making my header not to reach the border, even tho I erased all my margins and paddings and put  what you already told me. Shall I rewrite it in a new file in order to see if some tabulation is wrong?

Comment: The tabulation doesn't matter, consider them as comments. You don't have to apologize, it's just a tip in order of getting quicky and more readable answers for another person that maybe has some problem as you. I have removed the unnecessary parts. Now it works fine. In summary, the errors are - Remove all padding and margins at once ( with `*{margin:0; padding;0;}`, - correct order of opening and closing tabs, - and give the size of the photo in percentage (the width or the height, as you prefer).

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Maybe, since I edited it so many times an added and erase tabs in a wrong way. But after closing this post I want to answer; since I didnt learn any responsive method tll now, it is normal that in my desktop pc (27" of screen) I can see my website totally OK but in my laptop (16.5") the header is missplaced?

Comment: I recommend using flexbox for the navigation bar.

Comment: I solved it....I putted my section and articles inside a main and my header inside my body (I'm still new so I didn't know that caused the problem) and it solved the problem :) Thank you very much from all your help